# Creating a new variable from a lookup table

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following columns in my data set:

```
presult     aresult
  I         single
  I         double
  I         triple
  I         home run
  SS        strikeout
```

I would like to add a third column "bases" that is dependent upon the value of the result in column aresult.

For example, I would like bases to be 1 for a single, 2 for a double, 3 for a triple, 4 for a home run, and 0 for a strikeout.

Usually I would create the new variable like this:

```
dataset$base<-ifelse(dataset$aresult=="single", 1, 0)
```

The problem is that I don't know how to code the new variable in without setting all other variables to zero.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

define your lookup table

```
lookup= data.frame( 
        base=c(0,1,2,3,4), 
        aresult=c("strikeout","single","double","triple","home run"))
```

then use join from plyr

```
dataset = join(dataset,lookup,by='aresult')
```

Comment: a bit more verbose than the solution from Dieter but with this you have the flexibility to define the mapping aresult-> base.

Answer (score 16):

Here is how to use a named vector for the lookup:

Define test data:

```
dat <- data.frame(
    presult = c(rep("I", 4), "SS", "ZZ"),
    aresult = c("single", "double", "triple", "home run", "strikeout", "home run"),
    stringsAsFactors=FALSE
)
```

Define a named numeric vector with the scores:

```
score <- c(single=1, double=2, triple=3, `home run`=4,  strikeout=0)
```

Use vector indexing to match the scores against results:

```
dat$base <- score[dat$aresult]
dat
  presult   aresult base
1       I    single    1
2       I    double    2
3       I    triple    3
4       I  home run    4
5      SS strikeout    0
6      ZZ  home run    4
```

---

Additional information:

If you don't wish to construct the named vector by hand, say in the case where you have large amounts of data, then do it as follows:

```
scores <- c(1:4, 5)
names(scores) <- c("single", "double", "triple", "home run", "strikeout")
```

(Or read the values and names from existing data.  The point is to construct a numeric vector and then assign names.)

Comment: nice trick to use a named vector. I have learned something here.

Comment: +1 Great idea to use a named vector. Wish I'd seen/thought of this years ago!

Comment: @Andrie. Is there a way to do this without having to specify the rows. I have a dataset with thousands of rows.

Comment: @BurtonGuster I've added additional information.  I hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to [Dieter's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8433625/271616):

```
dat <- data.frame(
  presult = c(rep("I", 4), "SS", "ZZ"),
  aresult = c("single", "double", "triple", "home run", "strikeout", "home run"),
  stringsAsFactors=FALSE
)

dat$base <- as.integer(factor(dat$aresult,
  levels=c("strikeout","single","double","triple","home run")))-1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 dataset$base <- as.integer(as.factor(dataset$aresult))
```

Depending on your data as.factor() could be omitted, because in many cases strings are factor by default, e.g. with read.table

Comment: How can I specify what value each result takes?

Comment: Nice approach, but for this to work, "strikeout" needs to be first in the list, and then you have to subtract 1.

Comment: @burton my solution allows you to do that

Comment: @Andrie: or use `factor` instead of `as.factor` and specify the levels/labels however you want.