# how do I replace numeric codes with value labels from a lookup table?

Tags: r, replace, variable-assignment, dataframe, rename

This question is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8433523/creating-a-new-variable-from-a-lookup-table), but not quite the same.

Say I have this data frame,

```
df <- data.frame(
                id = c(1:6),
                profession = c(1, 5, 4, NA, 0, 5))
```

and a string with human readable information about the profession codes. Say,

```
profession.code <- c(
                     Optometrists=1, Accountants=2, Veterinarians=3, 
                     `Financial analysts`=4,  Nurses=5)
```

Now, I'm looking for the easiest way to replace the values in  `df$profession` with the text found in `profession.code`. Preferably without use of special libraries, unless it shortens the code significantly.

I would like my end result to be

```
df <- data.frame(
                id = c(1:6),
                profession = c("Optometrists", "Nurses", 
                "Financial analysts", NA, 0, "Nurses"))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Eric

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1:6),
                 profession = c(1, 5, 4, NA, 0, 5))

profession.code <- c(`0` = 0, Optometrists=1, Accountants=2, Veterinarians=3, 
                     `Financial analysts`=4,  Nurses=5)

df$profession.str <- names(profession.code)[match(df$profession, profession.code)]
df
#   id profession     profession.str
# 1  1          1       Optometrists
# 2  2          5             Nurses
# 3  3          4 Financial analysts
# 4  4         NA               <NA>
# 5  5          0                  0
# 6  6          5             Nurses
```

Note that I had to add a `0` entry in your `profession.code` vector to account for those zeroes.

EDIT: here is an updated solution to account for Eric's comment below that the data may contain any number of profession codes for which there are no corresponding descriptions:

```
match.idx <- match(df$profession, profession.code)
df$profession.str <- ifelse(is.na(match.idx),
                            df$profession,
                            names(profession.code)[match.idx])
```

Comment: Thank you for providing a solution. My problem is that the data gets passed to me from a database, and sometimes unexpected numbers are sent  _back to me_, so I could get any number, not only 0. I have to account for that in some way.

Answer (score 3):

I played around with it and this is my current solution using the `car` package.

```
pLoop <- function(v) paste(profession.code[v],"='", names(profession.code[v]),"';") 
library(car)
df$profession<- recode(df$profession, paste(sapply(1:5, pLoop),collapse=""))

df
# id           profession
#  1         Optometrists 
#  2               Nurses 
#  3   Financial analysts 
#  4                 <NA>
#  5                    0
#  6               Nurses
```

Still interest to if anyone have other suggestions for a solution. I would prefer to do it using only the base function in R.

Answer (score 1):

I personally like the way the `arules` package deals with this problem, using the `decode` function. From the documentation:

```
library(arules)
data("Adult")

## Example 1: Manual decoding
## get code
iLabels <- itemLabels(Adult)
head(iLabels)

## get undecoded list and decode in a second step
list <- LIST(Adult[1:5], decode = FALSE)
list

decode(list, itemLabels = iLabels)
```

Advantage is that the package also offers the functions `encode` and `recode`. Their respective purpose is straightforward, I believe.