# paste variable names inside R function

Tags: debugging, r, function

With the help of [flodel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1201032/flodel) I [found a way to replace numeric codes with value labels from a lookup table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10002536/how-do-i-replace-numeric-codes-with-value-labels-from-a-lookup-table).

Ambitious as I am, I now want to put that into a function. Also, I have a lot of lookup tables I need to swoop onto my data so a function would be handy.

But first some sample data, starting with a data fram,

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1:6),
                 profession = c(1, 5, 4, NA, 0, 5))

df
#  id profession
#  1          1
#  2          5
#  3          4
#  4         NA
#  5          0
#  6          5
```

and a lookup table with human readable information about the profession codes,

```
profession.lookuptable <- c(Optometrists=1, Accountants=2, Veterinarians=3, 
                            `Financial analysts`=4,  Nurses=5)
```

[flodel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1201032/flodel) showed me [how replace numeric codes with value labels from a lookup table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10002536/how-do-i-replace-numeric-codes-with-value-labels-from-a-lookup-table). Like this,

```
match.idx <- match(df$profession, profession.lookuptable)
df$profession <- ifelse(is.na(match.idx), 
                 df$profession, names(profession.lookuptable)[match.idx])

df
#  id         profession
#  1        Optometrists
#  2              Nurses
#  3  Financial analysts
#  4                <NA>
#  5                   0
#  6              Nurses
```

I now want to put this into a function where I can state the data frame `df` and the name of the variable `profession` and have the function take care of the rest.

I define my function like this,

```
ADDlookup <- function(orginalDF, orginalVAR) {
   DF.VAR <- paste(orginalDF, "$", orginalVAR, sep="")
   lookup.table <- paste(orginalVAR, ".lookuptable")
   match.idx <- match(DF.VAR, lookup.table)
   DF.VAR <- ifelse(is.na(match.idx), DF.VAR, names(lookup.table)[match.idx])
}
```

but apparently that is not working

```
ADDlookup(df, profession)
```

I get the errorer messes

```
Error in paste(orginalDF, "$", orginalVAR, sep = "") : 
  object 'profession' not found
```

Now, this is where I get stuck.

Can anyone please tell what manual page I need to read or maybe a friendly hint on how to solve this?

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you're passing `profession` into the `ADDlookup` function, but it doesn't exist yet.

The way you've written your function, you have to distinguish between using the *character vector containing the name of the variable*, and the *variable itself*.

For example, your first few lines `paste(originalDF,'$',originalVAR,sep='')` etc appear to expect `originalDF` and `originalVAR` to be *strings*, and you'll have `DF.VAR` being the *string* `'df$profession'`. However, when you do `match` it looks like you want `DF.VAR` to be the *variable* `df$profession`.

This is how I suggest you get around it:
- pass in `originalDF` as an object, being `df`
- pass in `originalVAR` as a *string*, being `'profession'` (it's a column name and hence a string)

Then, retrieve the *column* contained in `originalVar` from the data frame via:

```
DF.VAR <- originalDF[,originalVAR] # e.g. df[,'profession']
```

Now your next line where you look for the object `profession.lookuptable` is a little trickier: you construct the *string* `'profession.lookuptable'`, and then you want to look up the *object* that has that name.

For this, you can use `get` (`?get`). `get('df')` will return the `df` data frame:

```
lookup.table <- get(paste(orginalVAR, "lookuptable",sep='.'))
```

This will retrieve the object called `'profession.lookuptable'`. It follows the same rules as if you'd typed `profession.lookuptable` directly, so you have to make sure that the function can "see" that object (in your case you should be fine).

Next, it looks like you want to return the `originalDF` data frame where the `originalVAR` column has been substituted with the lookup values.

I'll just modify the `originalDF[,originalVAR]` column by replacing it with the lookup values:

```
originalDF[,originalVAR] <- 
   ifelse(is.na(match.idx), DF.VAR, names(lookup.table)[match.idx])
```

**NOTE** that we are *not* actually modifying the `df` data frame that you passed in as an argument to `ADDlookup`; R makes a *copy* of the data frame within the function. So, your original `df` is preserved.

Finally, we have to return the data frame:

```
return(originalDF)
```

All together now:

```
ADDlookup <- function(orginalDF, orginalVAR) {
   # retrieve the originalVAR column of originalDF
   DF.VAR <- originalDF[,originalVAR] 
   # find the variable called {originalVAR}.lookuptable
   lookup.table <- get(paste(originalVAR, "lookuptable",sep='.'))
   # look up the values
   match.idx <- match(DF.VAR, lookup.table)
   # replace the originalVAR column with the looked-up values
   originalDF[,originalVAR] <- 
       ifelse(is.na(match.idx), DF.VAR, names(lookup.table)[match.idx])
   # return the modified data frame
   return(originalDF)
}
```

And now to test it:

```
> ADDlookup(df,'profession')
  id         profession
1  1       Optometrists
2  2             Nurses
3  3 Financial analysts
4  4               <NA>
5  5                  0
6  6             Nurses
```

Note that the original `df` is unmodified; in general R functions do *not* modify the parameters that are passed in to them.

---

As another improvement -- it is generally a bit dangerous to rely on the `professions.lookup` table having been created before you call the `ADDlookup` function.

Instead of the whole `lookup.table <- get( 'profession.lookup' )` shebang (which, depending on if you have multiple 'profession.lookup' tables in various scopes), I'd strongly recommend you just pass in the lookup table as a parameter:

```
ADDlookup <- function( originalDF, originalVAR, lookup.table )
```

Then you can avoid that entire `get(xxxx)` line (and all associated scoping problems that go with it).

Then you'd call the function via:

```
ADDlookup( df, 'profession', profession.lookup )
```

Comment: +1 Ok, so it wasn't _that_ much more complicated, but I was trying to avoid using `get`.

Comment: Yeah, I don't like the use of `get` either; I've editted my post to mention that.

Comment: @mathematical.coffee Whooo, This is super informative. Thank you for taking the time to explain it all so thoroughly. It's probably me, but when I run your code I do get an error message when running the final function `Error in ADDlookup(df, "profession") : object 'originalDF' not found`. I'll take another look at it in the morning, it's late where I am. Once again, thank you for taking the time I'm definitely going to reread your post (several times). Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There are certainly more complicated ways to get this to work the way you originally envisioned, but it will be much, much simpler to simply reorganize how this function will work slightly:

```
ADDLookup <- function(originalDF,var,varLookup){
    match.idx <- match(originalDF[,var], varLookup)
    originalDF[,var] <- ifelse(is.na(match.idx), 
                        originalDF[,var], names(varLookup)[match.idx])
    originalDF
}                            

ADDLookup(df,"profession",profession.lookuptable)
  id         profession
1  1       Optometrists
2  2             Nurses
3  3 Financial analysts
4  4               <NA>
5  5                  0
6  6             Nurses
```

Note that now I'm passing the data frame, `df`, the name of the variable in question, `var` as a literal character and the lookup table itself as arguments.

Also, you've now learned why `$` is used more in interactive use than in programming! Because it doesn't mesh well with arguments passed in to functions. For that type of task you need the `[` syntax.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time and fixing my mess. I'm not sure I fully understand it all, but it get's the job done. Thanks!

Comment: shoulden't all the `df`'s inside the function be replaced with `originalDF`?

Answer (score 0):

I would define lookup table as factor.

```
df[,"profession"] <- profession.lookuptable[df[,"profession"]]
```