# how do I replace numeric codes in a data frame with value labels from a (data.frame) lookup table?

Tags: r, replace, variable-assignment, dataframe, rename

This is a followup question to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10002536/how-do-i-replace-numeric-codes-with-value-labels-from-a-lookup-table), initially inspired by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8433523/creating-a-new-variable-from-a-lookup-table), but not quite the same.

This is my situation. First I pull some data from a database,

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1:6),
                 profession = c(1, 5, 4, NA, 0, 5))
   df
#  id profession
#  1          1
#  2          5
#  3          4
#  4         NA
#  5          0
#  6          5
```

Second, I pull a key-table with human readable information about the profession codes,

```
profession.codes <- data.frame(profession.code = c(1,2,3,4,5),
                               profession.label = c('Optometrists',
                               'Accountants', 'Veterinarians', 
                               'Financial analysts',  'Nurses'))                 
   profession.codes
#  profession.code   profession.label
#               1       Optometrists
#               2        Accountants
#               3      Veterinarians
#               4 Financial analysts
#               5             Nurses
```

Now, I would like to overwrite the `profession` variable in my `df` with the labels from `profession.codes`, preferably using `join` from the `plyr` package, but I'm open to any smart solution. Though I do like that ply preserves the order of x.

I currently do it like this,

```
# install.packages('plyr', dependencies = TRUE)
library(plyr)

profession.codes$profession <- profession.codes$profession.code
df <- join(df, profession.codes, by="profession")
# levels(df$profession.label)
df$profession.label <- factor(df$profession.label, 
   levels = c(levels(df$profession.label), 
   setdiff(df$profession, df$profession.code)))
# levels(df$profession.label)
df$profession.label[df$profession==0 ] <- 0
df$profession.code <- NULL
df$profession  <- NULL
names(df) <- c("id", "profession")
df
#  id         profession
#  1       Optometrists
#  2             Nurses
#  3 Financial analysts
#  4               <NA>
#  5                  0
#  6             Nurses
```

This is how I overwrite `profession` without losing the `NA` and the `0`.

The problem is that the 0 could be a 17 or any number and I would like to account for that in some way. Furthermore, I would also like to shorten my code, if possible.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Eric

Comment: Not sure what you mean by: "0 could be a 17 or any number and I would like to account for that in some way"

Comment: @TylerRinker, in the example above there is only one value in `df$profession` that does not have a matching label in `profession.codes`. In the example the value is `0`, but it could also happen that other values showed up (if someone messes around with the database that I do not have control over). Your solution works even if several values in `df$profession` do not have a matching label in `profession.code`, which is great.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is one approach in base:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1:6),
                 profession = c(1, 5, 4, NA, 0, 5))

pc <- data.frame(profession.code = c(1,2,3,4,5),
                               profession.label = c('Optometrists',
                               'Accountants', 'Veterinarians', 
                               'Financial analysts',  'Nurses'))  


df$new <- as.character(pc[match(df$profession,  
    pc$profession.code), 'profession.label'])
df[is.na(df$new), 'new'] <- df[is.na(df$new), 'profession'] 
df$new <- as.factor(df$new)
df
```

Which yields:

```
  id profession                new
1  1          1       Optometrists
2  2          5             Nurses
3  3          4 Financial analysts
4  4         NA               <NA>
5  5          0                  0
6  6          5             Nurses
```

Comment: I did not overwrite the column you suggested as I am not a fan of overwriting something when you can just create a new column.  If you want to overwrite your orginal column then alter my solution to do this.

Comment: Agree both with match() solution AND not overwriting.

Comment: @TylerRinker, thank you for providing a solution. I like that you use the base. I too don't like to overwrite, but I have to in this specific case. The thing is that it's hard not to do a replace, as you do in the second line of your solution `(df[which(is.na(df$new)), 'new'] <- df[which(is.na(df$new)), 'profession'])` without using information from the original variable. To modify your solution I would add a line deleting the `$new`, like this `df$profession <- as.factor(df$new); df$new <- NULL`, unless there is a smarter solution? Thanks!

Comment: Yes that's likely how I'd approach it or assign the original df$profession to a duplicate object and use that in the line you correctly identify as needing the original df$professional.