# Annual data from different sources has different dates for the same year

Tags: r, match, lookup

I have merged data downloaded from different sources. The data is annual (one observation per year), but the dates are not consistently "anchored", e.g. I have "1992-12-31" or "1993-01-01". What is the recommended way to handle this sort of data? **How best to merge certain rows within a data.frame, based on a criterion of 'closeness' in the dates?**

There are existing questions and answers about merging rows within a dataframe, which could be applied to my situation with some adaptation, but here my question is specific to dates and the problem of handling the coexistence of "1992-12-31" and "1992-01-01" in annual data --- The data I have comes from institutions like the OECD, IMF, World Bank. Perhaps a clever package already knows the standard conventions of these institutions?

I am interested in both efficiency and readability of the code. I am also very much open to a data.table solution. Related question/answer not specifically about dates: [how do I replace numeric codes with value labels from a lookup table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10002536/how-do-i-replace-numeric-codes-with-value-labels-from-a-lookup-table)

**Input:**

```
    df <- structure(list(year = c("1992-12-31", "1993-01-01", "1993-12-31", "1994-01-01"), x = c(NA, 1, NA, 4), y = c(2, NA, 3, NA)), .Names = c("year", "x", "y"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
    df
    ##        year  x  y
    ##1 1992-12-31 NA  2
    ##2 1993-01-01  1 NA
    ##3 1993-12-31 NA  3
    ##4 1994-01-01  4 NA
```

**Desired Output:**

```
    df2
    ##        year x y
    ##1 1993-01-01 1 2
    ##2 1994-01-01 4 3
```

(assuming a mapping like this "1992-12-31" = "1993-01-01")

**A solution:**

```
    key <- c("1992-12-31" = "1993-01-01", 
             "1993-12-31" = "1994-01-01")
    matched <- match(df$year, names(key))
    df$year <- ifelse(is.na(matched),
                      df$year, key[matched])
    df
    ##        year  x  y
    ##1 1993-01-01 NA  2
    ##2 1993-01-01  1 NA
    ##3 1994-01-01 NA  3
    ##4 1994-01-01  4 NA
    df <- aggregate(x = df[c("x","y")], 
        by = list(year = df$year), mean, na.rm = TRUE)
    df
    ##        year x y
    ##1 1993-01-01 1 2
    ##2 1994-01-01 4 3
```

But I'm eager to learn if there is a cleverer way.

Side remark: I do realize that my existing dataset is already amenable to plotting, e.g. with `base R` or with `ggplot2`(Hadley Wickham):

```
plot(df1$x, df1$y)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df1, aes(x = year)) + geom_point(aes(y = x)) + geom_point(aes(y = y))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution using library `dplyr` is to assign ids to groups of dates that belong together and then summarize based on those groups:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  arrange(year) %>%
  mutate(id = cumsum(as.numeric(difftime(lead(df$year, default = max(year)), df$year, units = 'days')) == 1)) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(year = max(year), x = x[2], y = y[1]) %>%
  select(-id)
```

Output is as follows:

```
Source: local data frame [2 x 3]

        year     x     y
       (chr) (dbl) (dbl)
1 1993-01-01     1     2
2 1994-01-01     4     3
```

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply. So the key step here is in ``mutate``, with a combo of the functions ``difftime()`` and ``lead()``, with the ``max(year)`` argument. Not easy to follow the single line, but after breaking it down it makes sense. Not being familiar with ``dplyr`` I'll need to play around with this a little. Thanks for the help!

Comment: The best part about R and generally most package functions in R is that you can literally compute each single piece of that code separately and see what is going on. For example, you can just calculate `difftime` separate from everything else. Then, you can compute `cumsum` and see what you get and so on.....

Comment: Indeed thanks! Would you comment on the differences between your solution and zx8754, yours is longer but does not rely on the package ``lubridate``, are there differences in, say, robustness to (e.g. if a date other than 31 december were used, e.g. 1 June, would your code still work?)[I'm going to test all this asap, but it's labour day today] Perhaps you can comment about this and breaking down the steps in the body of your answer, if you think it would add value. Thanks!

Comment: You can try both on your data set and see which one is doing what and how well it fits your data. I can't say one is better than the other. This solution groups back-to-back dates. The other solution rolls a date into the following month, groups all dates that fall in a month and sums x / y. Depending on what else is in your data beyond what you provided, one may be better than the other.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe add one day for all dates, then round the dates to YYYYMM, then summarise.

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

#add one day then group
df %>% 
  mutate(year = ymd(year),
         YYYYMM = format(year + 1, "%Y%m")) %>% 
  group_by(YYYYMM) %>% 
  summarise(x = sum(x, na.rm = TRUE),
            y = sum(y, na.rm = TRUE))

#output
#   YYYYMM     x     y
#    (chr) (dbl) (dbl)
# 1 199301     1     2
# 2 199401     4     3
```

Comment: Or more generally `df %>% group_by(year = format(as.Date(year) + 1, "%Y-%m-01")) %>% summarise_each(funs(sum(., na.rm = TRUE)))`

Comment: @DavidArenburg agreed, we can prettify it, make it more efficient, etc. I am just trying to sell the idea of adding a number to round dates off into months.

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply. I'm not familiar with ``dplyr`` but it seems to be suited to this sort of manipulation. Your answer is very easy to follow. I'll play around with this on my data and come back in a couple of days to close the matter if I haven't experienced unexpected problems.  :-)