# How to test for multiple conditions in if else flow control in r

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement

It seems to be a very simple flow control structure doubt, however I am having a hard time finding the correct syntax for this in R, I have tried numerous without success. I must be missing something really obvious.

I wanted to loop in a list with Brazilian states codes, and return the region it is in. My aim is to manipulate a larger data set, not a list, but here is a MWE using a list:

```
a <- c("RO", "AC", "AM" ,"RR", "PA", "AP", "TO", "MA", "PI", "CE", "RN", "PB", "PE", "AL", "SE", "BA", "MG", "ES", "RJ", "SP")

setregion <- function(uf) {
  pb = txtProgressBar(min = 0, max = length(uf), initial = 0) 
  region_out<-list()
  for (i in length(uf)) {
    if (uf %in% c("RO"  ,"AC" ,"AM" ,"RR", "PA" , "AP" , "TO")) {
      region_out <- append(region_out,"North")
    } else if (  uf %in% c("MA","PI","CE","RN","PB","PE","AL","SE","BA")) {
      region_out <-append(region_out,"Northeast")
    } else if ( uf %in% c("MG","ES","RJ","SP")){
      region_out <- append(region_out,"Southeast")
    } else if ( uf %in% c("PR", "SC", "RS")){
      region_out <- append(region_out,"South") 
    } else if ( uf %in% c("MS","MT","GO", "DF")){
      region_out <-append(region_out,"Midwest")
    }
    setTxtProgressBar(pb,i)
  }
  return(region_out)
}

setregion(a)
```

Upon running the above code, it seems the if loop breaks the for loop as well, and it only returns "North", which is the response to the very first item in the list.

**I would expect a list with looking like:**

```
"North", "North", "North" ,"North", "North", "North","North", "Northeast", "Northeast",...
```

- What am I missing?

Comment: Could you show how your expected output should look like?

Comment: See above, as requested.

Comment: You can use a named vector as described e.g. here: [Creating a new variable from a lookup table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8433843/1851712). See also [Lookup tables (character subsetting), Matching and merging](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Subsetting.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with normal `if-else` is that it is not vectorized.  You need a vectorized approach, such as the `ifelse` function.  But, in your case, since you have so many conditions, the `case_when` function from the `dplyr` library might make more sense:

```
library(dplyr)

setregion <- function(uf) {
    region_out <- case_when(
        uf %in% c("RO","AC","AM","RR","PA","AP","TO") ~ "North",
        uf %in% c("MA","PI","CE","RN","PB","PE","AL","SE","BA") ~ "Northeast",
        uf %in% c("MG","ES","RJ","SP") ~ "Southeast",
        uf %in% c("PR", "SC", "RS") ~ "South",
        uf %in% c("MS","MT","GO", "DF") ~ "Midwest"
    )
    return(region_out)
}
```

Comment: This works, will have to spend some time with case_when function documentation.

Answer (score 3):

The best approach is to avoid to hard code this mapping; rather, it's much better to have it on a file/table and let the code be independent on such mapping (which might change in a second moment).

Consider to build a table like that (I might have made mistakes in associating the correct region, but whatever):

```
ufToRegionMap <- structure(list(uf = c("RO", "AC", "AM", "RR", "PA", "AP", "TO", 
"MA", "PI", "CE", "RN", "PB", "PE", "AL", "SE", "BA", "MG", "ES", 
"RJ", "SP", "PR", "SC", "RS", "MS", "MT", "GO", "DF"), region = c("North", 
"North", "North", "North", "North", "North", "North", "Northeast", 
"Northeast", "Northeast", "Northeast", "Northeast", "Northeast", 
"Northeast", "Northeast", "Northeast", "Southeast", "Southeast", 
"Southeast", "Southeast", "South", "South", "South", "Midwest", 
"Midwest", "Midwest", "Midwest")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-27L))
```

Then, you can define simply your function as such:

```
setregion <- function(uf, ufToRegionMap) {
   ufToRegionMap$region[match(uf,ufToRegionMap$uf)]
}
```

avoiding all the `if-else` headache and having a code that is naturally vectorized. Furthermore, if you want to change and create another region/association, you just change the `ufToRegionMap` with no need of changing the `setregion` function.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't like `case_when()` you could use `within()` and simple conditional assignment in your function.

```
regionizer <- function(dat, a) within(dat, {
  region_out[a %in% c("RO"  ,"AC" ,"AM" ,"RR", "PA" , "AP" , "TO")] <- "North"
  region_out[a %in% c("MA","PI","CE","RN","PB","PE","AL","SE","BA")] <- "Northeast"
  region_out[a %in% c("MG","ES","RJ","SP")] <- "Southeast"
  region_out[a %in% c("PR", "SC", "RS")] <- "South"
  region_out[a %in% c("MS","MT","GO", "DF")] <- "Midwest"
})

regionizer(dat, a)

#     a           x region_out
# 1  RO  0.15983063      North
# 2  AC -0.24371961      North
# 3  AM -0.52700098      North
# 4  RR  0.38777302      North
# 5  PA  0.91111258      North
# 6  AP -1.31696659      North
# 7  TO -0.16136374      North
# 8  MA -0.85951191  Northeast
# 9  PI  0.13187218  Northeast
# 10 CE -1.62908394  Northeast
...
```

***Data:*** `dat <- data.frame(a, x=rnorm(length(a)))`

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, this can be solved by merging / joining with a look-up table `lut`.

```
a <- c("RO", "AC", "AM" ,"RR", "PA", "AP", "TO", "MA", "PI", "CE", "RN", "PB", "PE", "AL", "SE", "BA", "MG", "ES", "RJ", "SP")

library(data.table)
library(magrittr)

# create look-up table from code snippets supplied by OP
lut <- list(
  North = c("RO"  ,"AC" ,"AM" ,"RR", "PA" , "AP" , "TO"),
  Northeast = c("MA","PI","CE","RN","PB","PE","AL","SE","BA"),
  Southeast = c("MG","ES","RJ","SP"),
  South = c("PR", "SC", "RS"),
  Midwest = c("MS","MT","GO", "DF")
) %>% 
  lapply(as.data.table) %>% 
  rbindlist(idcol = "region")

# update join
as.data.table(a)[lut, on = .(a == V1), region_out := region][]
```

> ```
>      a region_out
>  1: RO      North
>  2: AC      North
>  3: AM      North
>  4: RR      North
>  5: PA      North
>  6: AP      North
>  7: TO      North
>  8: MA  Northeast
>  9: PI  Northeast
> 10: CE  Northeast
> 11: RN  Northeast
> 12: PB  Northeast
> 13: PE  Northeast
> 14: AL  Northeast
> 15: SE  Northeast
> 16: BA  Northeast
> 17: MG  Southeast
> 18: ES  Southeast
> 19: RJ  Southeast
> 20: SP  Southeast
> ```

The look-up table was constructed from the code snippets provided by the OP:

> ```
>        region V1
>  1:     North RO
>  2:     North AC
>  3:     North AM
>  4:     North RR
>  5:     North PA
>  6:     North AP
>  7:     North TO
>  8: Northeast MA
>  9: Northeast PI
> 10: Northeast CE
> 11: Northeast RN
> 12: Northeast PB
> 13: Northeast PE
> 14: Northeast AL
> 15: Northeast SE
> 16: Northeast BA
> 17: Southeast MG
> 18: Southeast ES
> 19: Southeast RJ
> 20: Southeast SP
> 21:     South PR
> 22:     South SC
> 23:     South RS
> 24:   Midwest MS
> 25:   Midwest MT
> 26:   Midwest GO
> 27:   Midwest DF
>        region V1
> ```