# Column values based on different column

Tags: r

I am working on R and I have the following data frame `data`:

| country | index | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 0 | 15 |
| B | 1 | 15 |
| C | 2 | 15 |
| D | 3 | 15 |
| E | 4 | 15 |
| F | 5 | 15 |

How could I map values so that I get an extra column `EXTRA` with specific information. For example I want to pass information (in any form) that countries with index 0,1 and 2 should have value  `first` in `EXTRA`, 3 and 5 should have `second` and 4 for example `eleventh`.  So the expected output would look like this:

| country | index | value | EXTRA |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 0 | 15 | first |
| B | 1 | 15 | first |
| C | 2 | 15 | first |
| D | 3 | 15 | second |
| E | 4 | 15 | eleventh |
| F | 5 | 15 | second |

Comment: Related: [Creating a new variable from a lookup table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8433523/creating-a-new-variable-from-a-lookup-table) (describes two common methods: named vector and join/merge)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use a named vector to match and replace

```
nm1 <- setNames(c('first', 'first', 'first', 'second', 'eleventh', 'second'), 0:5)
df1$EXTRA <- nm1[as.character(df1$index)]
```

---

Or can use a join

```
library(data.table)
keydat <- data.frame(index = 0:5,
    EXTRA = c('first', 'first', 'first', 'second', 'eleventh', 'second'))
setDT(df1)[keydat, EXTRA := EXTRA, on = .(index)]
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(country = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"), index = 0:5, 
    value = c(15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L)), class = "data.frame",
    row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: Is there a more another approach in case the `data.frame` has a huge amount of values?

Comment: @CroatiaHR This would be very fast.  Other option is `merge` or `join` which can be a bit slow

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option using nested `ifelse`

```
transform(
  df,
  EXTRA = ifelse(index %in% 0:2,
    "first",
    ifelse(index %in% c(3, 5),
      "second",
      "eleventh"
    )
  )
)
```

or `merge` + `stack`

```
merge(df,
  setNames(
    stack(list(first = 0:2, second = c(3, 5), eleventh = 4)),
    c("index", "EXTRA")
  ),
  by = "index",
  all.x = TRUE
)
```

which gives

```
  country index value    EXTRA
1       A     0    15    first
2       B     1    15    first
3       C     2    15    first
4       D     3    15   second
5       E     4    15 eleventh
6       F     5    15   second
```